# Kivy buildozer apk created but crashes on android

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer, pygsheets

I'm working on an app, and my code works perfectly. I was also able to make the apk. But when I ran it, it didn't work properly. My app uses pygsheets, so I thought that the reason might be some missing requirement, but I'm not sure what it is. Please help. Link to log is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1B3Izl8VbgorCb-oyV6o-QQye9wKqEh8ObiYf2NPLgpI/edit?usp=drivesdk). I'm not very sure how I'm supposed to use this to figure out the problem.
Edit: Using a try except block and writing error to text file I found it to be error message to be no module named google. It was during the import pygsheets statement. Any idea on how to solve this ? I'll add my buildozer.spec file here, so please take a look at my requirements section and tell me if anything is missing. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OkZuW31ugHWEGn8XbIpQRnlWgBwSPt-M/view?usp=drivesdk. I put all the requirements of pygsheets in, so I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: how are you authorizing pygsheets?

Comment: I'm using a json file that serves as the key. I've added the json extension to the buildozer file, so I'm sure that's not the problem. I can attach the buildozer file here if that would help.

Comment: use logcat to get the app logs

Comment: See I'm running buildozer on google colab. So can't really attach device. I did still run logcat, the output of which is at the end of the file linked.

Comment: without proper logs its hard to say what the issue is. 2 places where pygsheets could cause issue is auth and accessing the API specs document.

Comment: Plase look at my edit

Comment: @Nithin plase check my update.

Comment: @AnkitSangwan please check my update.

Comment: See the thing about requirements is one requirement might depend on the other one. Like you are using pygsheets which might depend on any other module. That's why I said to use logcat as It will give you the details regarding what module you are missing. Then just add that module in your requirements section. "Build Log" is required when any problem while building occurs as there's no problem while building it's of no use. What you need are "App Logs". I understand that you are using google colab, then just install the app in any device and download adb drivers in your pc.

Comment: I hope you know how to use adb drivers. You can google it for download link and how to use adb to get app logs. You might have to repeat the process 3-4 times as there can be multiple missing modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I first added all the requirements of the pygsheet module which aren't directly shown by pip show. Then I had to specify the version as there are specific version requirements. google-api-python-client had to be version 1.11.0 and six had to be version greater than 1.12.0.